# Generating a vector with values based conditionally from other vectors

Tags: r

Say I have two vectors.

```
a <- c(1,5)
b <- c(2,3,4,6)
```

I would like to create a vector from this two vectors such that positions in the new vector in 'a' is red and 'b' is blue, result

```
c <- c('red','blue','blue','blue','red','blue')
```

I think may be using rep would help, but for example some sort of ifelse within the rep based off `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
cols <- rep(NA,length(a)+length(b))
cols[a] <- "red"
cols[b] <- "blue"

cols
#  [1] "red"  "blue" "blue" "blue" "red"  "blue"
```

Comment: brilliant! I was trying hard to figure this one out. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `stack`.  Get the `vector` objects in a `list` with `mget`, `stack` to create the `data.frame`, `transform` the 'ind' column to `factor` with `labels` as 'red', 'blue', get the 'ind' after `order`ing the 'values'.

```
d1 <- transform(stack(mget(c('a', 'b'))), ind = factor(ind, labels = c('red', 'blue')))
as.character(d1$ind[order(d1$values)])
#[1] "red"  "blue" "blue" "blue" "red"  "blue"
```

As @Frank stated, with this method, more than 2 vectors can be `sort`ed out

Comment: Worth noting: this is the only way posted so far that will extend at all cleanly to more vectors (beyond the two, a and b).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more general solution compared to @MattTyers neat one:

```
cols <- sort(c(a,b))
cols[cols %in% a] <- "red"
cols[cols %in% b] <- "blue"
cols
# [1] "red"  "blue" "blue" "blue" "red"  "blue"
```